# Continuous calculations on-the-go in Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator, user-experience

I have a simple calculator made in JS and works well, but when I finish my calculation and get my result (i.e. pressing the "=" button), I want the returned result to be in a *saved* state. The "=" button must be ready to be clicked again, and get the same result, and then add it to the save result.

I've tried many obvious ways, such as adding the result to itself (which doesn't work because the result will be multiplied by itself, not added), exploiting the eval() function and adding a "+" string to the end result, etc.

**TLDR**: If you go to any calculator program, and type "**2+2**" and click equals, you get **4**. If you click equals again, you get **6** ("**2+2+2**").

Here's my current code:

```
var disp = document.getElementById("calc-output"),
  acceptedInputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "-", ".", "+", "*", "/"];

function ud(n) {
  if (acceptedInputs.includes(n)) {
    if (disp.innerHTML.length == 31) {
      disp.innerHTML = 0;
    }
    if (disp.innerHTML.length < 18) {
      if (disp.innerHTML != 0) {
        disp.innerHTML += n;
      } else if (acceptedInputs.slice(11, -1).includes(n)) {
        disp.innerHTML = 0 + n;
      } else if (disp.innerHTML.toString().slice(1, 2) == ".") {
            if (disp.innerHTML.toString().split(".").length-1 <= 1) {
                disp.innerHTML += n;
            }
      } else {
        disp.innerHTML = n;
      }
    }
  }
}

function answer() {
  if (eval(disp.innerHTML) == disp.innerHTML) {
    disp.innerHTML = disp.innerHTML + "+"
  }
  c = eval(disp.innerHTML);
  disp.innerHTML = c;
}

function clear() {
  disp.innerHTML = "0";
}

function back() {
  var str = disp.innerHTML.toString();
  if (disp.innerHTML != 0 || str.charAt(1) == ".") {
    if (str.length >= 2) {
      str = str.slice(0, -1);
      disp.innerHTML = str;
    } else {
      disp.innerHTML = 0;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("n1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(1);
});
document.getElementById("n2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(2);
});
document.getElementById("n3").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(3);
});
document.getElementById("n4").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(4);
});
document.getElementById("n5").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(5);
});
document.getElementById("n6").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(6);
});
document.getElementById("n7").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(7);
});
document.getElementById("n8").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(8);
});
document.getElementById("n9").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(9);
});
document.getElementById("zero-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud(0);
});
document.getElementById("comma-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud('.');
});

document.getElementById("plus-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud('+');
});
document.getElementById("minus-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud('-');
});
document.getElementById("multi-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud('*');
});
document.getElementById("div-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ud('/');
});
document.getElementById("back-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  back();
});
document.getElementById("clear-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clear();
});
document.getElementById("equals-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  answer();
});
```

Comment: Currently this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  You're showing a lot of code, but not a minimal and complete example of the problem.  And the "problem" is that you'd like to add features to a working program but have made no attempt yet to do so.  We encourage you to make such an attempt.  For example, when you say *"I want the returned result to be saved"*, what's stopping you from saving that value?  Save it to a variable.  Can you then use that variable later?  If it needs to exist in a different scope, save it in a different scope, etc.  When you try, where do you get stuck?

Comment: I've tried saving the result in a variable in the function where the result is calculated, but obviously that variable gets changed each time the function is called, and leads to the same problem with the result multiplying itself, not adding. I thought of adding an array at the beginning of the code to store the result the function returns, but the function is set to modify the _.innerHTML_ of the output element, not return a value.

Comment: Having made an attempt is a *good* first step.  Now, when you make an attempt, what *specific* problem do you encounter?  We can't really help with questions like this: "I tried to build something but I don't know how, can someone do it for me and show me how?"  But we *can* help with questions like this: "In this specific small example I've tried to do this specific thing, but on this specific line I'm seeing a value of this variable that I don't expect.  Why is that?"  Narrow the problem, provide details, etc.  We can help you understand why any given attempt didn't work.

Comment: To learn more about what this community does and how we can help you, you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Save the last operation (e.g. " + 2") in some variable when user clicks equal. So, when he clicks again, just append saved value to the string from display.

```
var lastOperation = null;

function answer() {
    if (eval(disp.innerHTML) == disp.innerHTML) {
        // apply the last operation to displayed number
        disp.innerHTML = disp.innerHTML + (lastOperation ? lastOperation[0] : '');
    }
    // find the last operation + | - | * | /
    lastOperation = disp.innerHTML.split(new RegExp('(\\+|\\-|\\*|/).*$'));
    c = eval(disp.innerHTML);
    disp.innerHTML = c;
}
```